# Google Maps zoomControl hide and show

Tags: javascript, maps

I have encountered a problem when using the custom google maps controls. What I want is to show the zoomControl when switching to the map and hide the zoomControl in other view using map as a static background. My code is like this,

```
if (isMapView) {
  map.setOptions({
      zoomControl: true,
      zoomControlOptions: {position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP}
    });
} else {
  map.setOptions({
      zoomControl: false
    });
}
```

But this doesnt work, the first switch is fine and latter ones the zoomControl is disappeared. I dont know why. Could anyone give a hand?

Answer (score 8):

I am searching for this long time. But your question really helped me. I just did the same thing as you posted. It is working for me.I have added two buttons. On first button click i call DoSomething. on second, DoSomething2. It works fine. Thanks for your post. Look this, if anything helps.

```
     function DoSomething()
    {
        map.setOptions({zoomControl: true, mapTypeControl: true});
    }

    function DoSomething2()
    {
        map.setOptions({zoomControl: false, mapTypeControl: false});
    }
```

Comment: I stumbled across this answer looking for disableDefaultUI; In case someone else does too: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/LMECRuzlbcI