# Google Maps API V3 - adding controls on the fly

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm initializing a map with no controls because I've implemented some custom zoom controls in my page.

However, I'd like to add the standard zoom controls back to the map under specific circumstances, namely when I detect the window has been resized to a certain width. Conversely I would like to destroy them again at larger widths.

Is it possible to add the zoom control on the fly and if so, how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps zoomControl hide and show](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205036/google-maps-zoomcontrol-hide-and-show)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the API version 3 use `setOptions` to set `zoomControl` to true/false (similar question [Dynamically add/remove controls [Google Maps]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23919210/dynamically-add-remove-controls-google-maps/31856505)).

Demo:

```js
// create map
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-33, 151);
var myOptions = {
  center: myLatlng,
  zoom: 5,
  zoomControl: false,
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);


// functions for removing zoomControl
function toggleZoomControl(b) {
  map.setOptions({
    zoomControl: b
  });
}
```

```css
#map_canvas {
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="toggleZoomControl(this.checked)" />zoomControl
```